# how to text-align columns in DataGrid? (a rational way)

Tags: wpf, datagrid, styles, text-alignment

I use WPF (C #). I use DataGrid.
I want the first column is aligned with the center, the other columns are right-aligned.

I general have style:

```
<Style x:Key="TextInCellCenter" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" >
     <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">       
     <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
</Style>
```

DataGrids:

```
<DataGrid Name="DG1">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn ElementStyle="{StaticResource TextInCellCenter}" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Number}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Number}" />
    ....
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Number}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Number}" />
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

<DataGrid Name="DG2">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn ElementStyle="{StaticResource TextInCellCenter}" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Number}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Number}" />
    ...
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Number}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Number}" />
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
....
```

I have **all the columns are right-aligned**.

Please tell me, how do I change the **first column** had a **center text-alignment**?

p.s. How to do it in a rational way? I've got a lot of similar tables.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of changing style of `DataGridCell` you can change `ElementStyle` for `TextBlock` and change `TextAlignment` to be `Right` or `Center` and apply it on per column basis

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Number}" >
   <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
         <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Right"/>
      </Style>
   </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

or create this `Style` in `DataGrid.Resources` so you can apply to more then one column

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="TextInCellCenter" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" >
            <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="RightAligElementStyle">
            <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Right"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn ElementStyle="{StaticResource TextInCellCenter}" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Number}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource RightAligElementStyle}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Number}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource RightAligElementStyle}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Number}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource RightAligElementStyle}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>        
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: thanks, but the first method does not work, and second method is inconvenient, because I have more than 10 tables in which a lot of adding identical columns (like column "Number"). Define a style for each same column takes a lot of time.